# Where to add BUTTONSOURCE property to javascript for Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

First, thanks to anyone that responds, I really appreciate it.
I am working on implementing paypal express checkout. 
I am looking where to add the BUTTONSOURCE property to the javascript that opens the paypal window but cannot find within the paypal documentation where to do that.
Should it occur in the paypal.Button.render method?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? how did it fail?

Comment: I have tried the following code:
 paypal.Button.render({
              env: <ENVIRONMENT>, // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment
              buttonsource: '<CODE>',
              locale: <LOCALE>,
              style: {  <OPTIONS>  },
               .....

Comment: It does not fail per se, but does not pass along the appropriate values.